# using the make command for a minimalOS from a gcc and binutils setup

Tags: c, linux, gcc, binutils

I have a kernel.c file that I have edited but then when I go back to run make before I would then run the make run command I get this error.

[linux error lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04Gqp.png)

I'm not very clued up in any of this but I don't understand why changes in my c file have changes the way the make happens?

this is on an ubuntu 16.4 system running on vmware

edit: I replaced the changed c file with the an initial backup that worked but I still get the same error meaning the c file is not the problem

edit: I reinstalled gcc and it works now this question no longer needs an answer.

Comment: The error is telling you it can't find gcc (it is looking for a 32-bit version, perhaps that is the problem?)

Comment: What could i possibly have changed to make this happen as it worked fine recently? or what can I do to make it find my gcc as it is supposed to be 32 bit?